# Identify atoms in chemical equation

Tags: chemistry, mhchem

I am trying to represent an exchange reaction in N2 + N, where the reactant atomic N is swapped for one in N2. I'm using the `mhchem` package, and currently have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

The exchange reaction is:

\begin{align}
   \ce{ N^{(1)} \bond{1} N^{(2)} + N^{(3)} 
     -> N^{(1)} \bond{1} N^{(3)} + N^{(2)} }
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: Current output]

I'm unhappy with this for several reasons.

- It's not immediately clear that the superscript numbers are atomic identifiers.
- The spacing between bonded atoms is about the same as the spacing between molecules (`+` vs `-`). I think having more space between molecules or less space between bonded atoms would help.

Perhaps I just need to fiddle with the spacing, especially because the superscripts are adding space. What is the best way to do that inside an `mhchem` equation?

Alternatively, I could completely ditch the superscript atomic identifiers and use a more clear distinction. Obviously, I need to specify that the reactant atomic N is now a component of N2, but how? Any suggestions are welcome.

### Edit 1

Removing the parenthesis and the space between bonds, as suggested in the comments,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

New:
%
\begin{align*}
   \ce{ N^{1}-N^{2} + N^{3}
     -> N^{1}-N^{3} + N^{2} }
\end{align*}

Old:
%
\begin{align*}
   \ce{ N^{(1)} \bond{1} N^{(2)} + N^{(3)}
     -> N^{(1)} \bond{1} N^{(3)} + N^{(2)} }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Updated with suggestions]

This is clearly better, but the spacing before the bond (due to the superscript) still looks too large. What is the best way to fiddle with this?

Comment: What about using colors? `\ce{ N \bond{1} N + \textcolor{green}{N}
     -> N \bond{1} \textcolor{green}{N} + N }` with `xcolor.sty` loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd rather stick with black and white. It's for a journal paper and I'm not planning for anything to be in color. Perhaps some other way of picking out the initial atomic N?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use a colored (gray or black) background: `\ce{ N \bond{1} N + \colorbox{gray}{N} -> N \bond{1} \colorbox{gray}{N} + N }`. If you want to get rid of the spacing, adjust `\fboxsep`.

Comment: Don't leave spaces around the bonds: `\ce{ N^{(1)}\bond{1}N^{(2)} + N^{(3)}  -> N^{(1)}\bond{1}N^{(3)} + N^{(2)} }`. Or simpler `\ce{ N^{(1)}-N^{(2)} + N^{(3)} -> N^{(1)}-N^{(3)} + N^{(2)} }`. Personally, I'd just use superscripted numbers without parentheses `\ce{N^{1}-N^2 + N^3 -> N^{1}-N^3 + N^2}`. It is not uncommon to mark different substituents this way (`\ce{R^{1}-R^2}`).

Comment: @clemens I hadn't noticed the difference with and without the space around `\bond{1}`, thanks. Unfortunately, I've actually been using the `\ce{N-N}` notation in practice. I like the suggestion about no parenthesis.

Comment: Maybe using `chemfig` is an option? `\schemestart \chemfig{N^1-N^2} \+ \chemfig{N^3} \arrow \chemfig{N^1-N^3} \+ \chemfig{N^2} \schemestop` (the input is more verbose, but…)

Comment: If you use the `mathtools` package, you can use `\mathrlap` to avoid the superscript to consume any space (`N\mathrlap{^1}`), thus the atom-bond-gap is the same as without superscripts. However, I think this is not very readable. I am pretty sure that`mhchem`offers an option to (locally) change the atom-bond-gap, and it might be possible to find a good solution combining an increased gap-width and `\mathrlap`.

Comment: I'm going to go with the @clemens answer, so if you want to write it up I'm happy to accept it. Otherwise, I'll post my own answer so it's clear in the future. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: don't leave spaces around the bonds:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\ce{
     N^{(1)} \bond{1} N^{(2)} + N^{(3)} 
  -> N^{(1)} \bond{1} N^{(3)} + N^{(2)}
}

\ce{
     N^{(1)}\bond{1}N^{(2)} + N^{(3)} 
  -> N^{(1)}\bond{1}N^{(3)} + N^{(2)}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Instead of `\bond{1}` it also suffices to input `-`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\ce{
     N^{(1)}\bond{1}N^{(2)} + N^{(3)} 
  -> N^{(1)}\bond{1}N^{(3)} + N^{(2)}
}

\ce{
     N^{(1)}-N^{(2)} + N^{(3)} 
  -> N^{(1)}-N^{(3)} + N^{(2)}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally I'd also leave the parentheses away. It is not uncommon to mark different substituents with supersctipt numbers (*cf.* `\ce{R^1}`). In my opionion the message becomes even clearer without the parentheses:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\ce{
     N^{(1)}-N^{(2)} + N^{(3)} 
  -> N^{(1)}-N^{(3)} + N^{(2)}
}

\ce{
     N^{1}-N^2 + N^3 
  -> N^{1}-N^3 + N^2
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course colors also work (unless you're colorblind):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\ce{
     {\textcolor{red}{N}}-\textcolor{blue}{N} + \textcolor{green}{N} 
  -> {\textcolor{red}{N}}-\textcolor{green}{N} + \textcolor{blue}{N}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

And just as a comparison using `chemfig`:

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \chemfig{N^1-N^2} \+ \chemfig{N^3}
  \arrow
  \chemfig{N^1-N^3} \+ \chemfig{N^2}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here the length of bond and arrow is easily customizable.